# How to make .htaccess ignore css, js, images and href (links)

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please pardon my writing, I am new to .htaccess but i've checked many examples but they are not working.

Below are my files directories

**parent/css/style.css 

parent/js/script.js 

parent/image/example.png**

I have a php file in the root directory **parent/discussion-forum.php**

Everything works fine except the href (links), if I rewrite it to **parent/discussion** 
    `RewriteRule ^discussion discussion-forum.php [NC,L]`

I face the following problems if i rewrite it to **parent/forum** 
`RewriteRule ^forum discussion-forum.php [NC,L]`

- **parent/css/style.css** becomes **parent/forum/css/style.css**
- **parent/js/script.js** becomes **parent/forum/js/script.css**
- Images becomes **parent/forum/image/example.png**
- links (href) to other page on **parent/discussion-forum.php** becomes **parent/forum/example.php** instead of **parent/example.php**
- Every file with the name forum e.g **parent/forum-discussion-view.php** is redirected back to **parent/forum**

Please help me with .htaccess solution to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't have need to edit the .htaccess, but just put a **$base_href** var in your php code, like that:

$base_href = "http://www.example.com";

And in every includes that you make:

```
<link href="<?php echo $base_href ?>/css/style.css">
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, i've previously used absolute path for the css and javascript and it worked but i need an htaccess solution so that i can use relative path and also the link are still redirected back to forum even after using absolute path.